# $v^TAv\ge \left\|A\right\|\cdot\left\|v\right\|_2$ for all positive definite $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be positive definite and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\left\|\cdot\right\|_2$ be the Euclidean norm. Can we prove $$v^TAv\ge \left\|A\right\|\cdot\left\|v\right\|_2$$
for a matrix norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|$? I think **we can** and as far as I remember, it has something to do with the (positive) eigenvalues of $A$, but I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 6):

The inequality $$v^TAv\ge \left\|A\right\|\cdot\left\|v\right\|_2$$
is false for reasons of scaling.

Fix some non-zero $v$. Take $\lambda$ a positive prameter, and consider the expression for $\lambda v$. The left-hand side scales like $\lambda^2$ the right-hand side like $\lambda$. Take $\lambda$ very small.

Comment: What if $A=\nabla^2f(x)-\nabla^2f(x+\xi v)$, $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\xi\in [0,1]$ and $\nabla^2f(x)$ positive definite?

Comment: The inequality cannot hold under any reasonable circumstances, for the reason I gave.